# WebStorm unknown directive @client with Apollo-Client 3 warning

Tags: typescript, graphql, webstorm, apollo-client

Wondering how to fix the warning WebStorm is giving me for apollo-client. I have the GraphQL plugin installed and everything is up to date with the IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
directive @client on FIELD
```

in the same file solved the issue in WebStorm.

Overall, even with WebStorm showing the error, GraphQL code generators understood this syntax and obviously no errors were reported.